# DialogFragment и данные

Tags: java, android

Во время использования диалогового(создается с помощью `DialogFragment`) окна вознила необходимость передавать данные из диалогового окна в основную активностьи выполнять определенный метод. Сейчас вызываю метод путем надатия на скрытую кнопку(да-да костыль) и обрабатываю нажатие.
Диалоговое окно создаю так:

```
Chname qq = new Chname();

qq.show(fm, "dlg");
```

где `Chname` - мой класс, наследованный от `DialogFragment`

Вопросы:

1)Как в основном `activity` можно обработаь событие "закрытие диалогового окна"?
2)Возможно ли вызывать методы основного `activity` через диалоговое окно?

Comment: 1) А как у вас происходит закрытие диалога? 2) Какие методы, например?

Comment: 1)Закрытие происходит при нажатии на кнопки "ок" и "отмена", которые создаются следующтм образом: '(builder.setTitle("Введите новое имя").setView(form)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.submit_name, this).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null).create());'

Comment: 2)А есть разница? Предположим что просто любой метод который я сам написал в классе активити

Comment: А нарисовать диалогу интерфейс и зарегистрировать его в активити?

Comment: Интерфейс у диалога задан. *вопрос делитанта* - как зарегистрировать его в активити?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел еще один вариант - позволяет создаавть диолог, не плодя еще один класс

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
builder.setTitle("Важное")
        .setMessage("ошибка")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_android_cat)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setNegativeButton("ОК",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       //someMethods()
                    }
                });
```

Вот так в данном случае будет у Вас. Если же надо отследить по нажатию на кнопку "назад", то скорей всего надо будет еще завести булову переменную и в перекрытом `onBackPressed` смотреть открыт диалог или нет

Comment: То есть метод onClick будет вызываться при нажатии на кнопку "ок"  в диалоговом окне, я правильно понял?

Comment: в setPositiveButton по аналогии перекройте onClick тогда, и все будет работать)

Comment: Так, еще дилетантский такой вопрос: как мне получить из основного класса доступ к билдеру в диалоговом окне? и "getString(R.string.cancel)" - для чего мы строку берем? =)

Comment: 1) Приведите на примере, что именно надо получить или что сделать в итоге 2) getString(R.string.cancel) Это на кнопки навешивать текст из строковых ресурсов res/values/strings.xml

Comment: Давайте чтоб было понятней распишу то, как оно должно работать: 1) в основном активити создается диалоговое окно 2) в нем вводятся данные 3) при нажатии на "ок" - данные передеются в основное активити (с этим я справился) 4) после нажатия на "ок" и передачи данных в основное активити - должен вызваться метод который обрабатывает полученные данные

Comment: При этом обрабаываться они должны именно в основном активити, так как в нем запущен необходимый сервис(подключение по bluetooth)

Comment: исходники прикрепите, так проще будет

Comment: С исходниками не получится(. Я тут сообразил что наверное легче будет из диалога поключиться к работающему сервису. Буду двигаться в этом направлении, спасибо большое, очень помогли!)

Comment: всегда пожалуйста)

Answer (score 0):

Вышел из положения следующим способом: после создания объекта диалога - передаю в него необходимый объект.

Chname qq = new Chname();

qq.variableQQ = variableFromActivity;

qq.show(fm, "dlg");

Comment: не надо так делать. вы поймете это через год-другой :)

Comment: Да, костыль) Но пока не сильно соображаю в передачи данные между активити и сервисами - прокатит)